# Yii::app()->user->isGuest is returning null

Tags: php, exception, authentication, yii

**Yii::app()->user->isGuest** is throwing exception as

`"Uncaught exception 'CException' with message 'Property "CWebUser.email" is not defined."`

how can i solve this error?

Comment: Since Yii is an open source application you're going to need to list the exact version you're using (reason is that it could be a bug in the specific version you're using) and perhaps give some context as to what you are trying to do and where you are trying to do it. As this question stands, it'd be hard for someone to accurately answer it for you.

Comment: Kindly add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `username` is mandatory to use in the `CWebUser` class. If you want to use the users e-mail as username, you have to assign `email` to the `username` variable. More info on how to do this can you find on Larry Ullman's page:

http://www.larryullman.com/2010/01/07/custom-authentication-using-the-yii-framework/

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't set the email. 
open the file at "protected -> components -> UserIdentity.php". Add `$this->setState('email', $user->email)` as below.

```
$this->_id=$user->id;
$this->username=$user->username;
$this->setState('email', $user->email);
```